# Position of WHERE statement in left outer join

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the following query I am trying to first, filter all subscriptions that have a `network_id` = 24, and then join the column `payment_plans.plan_type` to subscriptions where the `ids` are the same.

I think there is a problem in the positioning of the `WHERE` statement but I am not sure where it is - the error shows that the there is a syntax error near the join statement

Any suggestions as to where the error might be?

```
SELECT DISTINCT subscriptions.user_id, subscriptions.payment_plan_id, payment_plans.plan_type
FROM subscriptions WHERE network_id = 24
LEFT OUTER JOIN payment_plans ON subscription.payment_plan_id = payment_plans.id


ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LEFT"
LINE 3: LEFT OUTER JOIN payment_plans ON subscription.payment_plan_i...
        ^
```

Comment: In which table is the column `network_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subscriptions.user_id, subscriptions.payment_plan_id, payment_plans.plan_type
FROM subscriptions 
LEFT OUTER JOIN payment_plans ON subscription.payment_plan_id = payment_plans.id
WHERE network_id = 24
```

You can check out the [documentation for the SELECT statement, in particular this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql).

Answer (score 2):

The SQL syntax is `select ... from ... join .. on ..where`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT subscriptions.user_id, subscriptions.payment_plan_id, payment_plans.plan_type
FROM subscriptions 
LEFT OUTER JOIN payment_plans ON subscription.payment_plan_id = payment_plans.id
WHERE network_id = 24
```

That is SQL standart and the same for all RDBMS.

Comment: We all posted identical answers. Why did you got a downwote, it's beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Move your where after the join statement. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subscriptions.user_id, subscriptions.payment_plan_id, 
payment_plans.plan_type
FROM subscriptions 
LEFT OUTER JOIN payment_plans ON subscription.payment_plan_id = 
payment_plans.id 
WHERE network_id = 24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

`SELECT DISTINCT subscriptions.user_id, subscriptions.payment_plan_id, payment_plans.plan_type
FROM subscriptions LEFT OUTER JOIN payment_plans ON subscription.payment_plan_id = payment_plans.id
WHERE subscriptions.network_id = 24`